# How to fix TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable numpy.float64 object in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to create a custom peak detection algorithm, however, I keep on getting the with regards to unpacking the NumPy object. The error can be found below:

```
for x_v, y_v in y_ax:

TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable numpy.float64 object
```

The code which implements the custom peak detection can be found below:

```
def custom_peakdetection(y_axis, peak_height, x_axis=None):
    """
    keyword arguments:
    y_axis -- A list containing the signal over which to find peaks
    x_axis -- (optional) A x-axis whose values correspond to the 'y_axis' list and is used in the return to specify the position of the peaks. If omitted the index of the y_axis is used. (default: None)
    peak_height -- This specifies a minimum height of the peak
    
    return -- two lists [maxtab, mintab] containing the positive and negative peaks respectively. Each cell of the lists contains a tuple of:
    (position, peak_value) to get the average peak value do 'np.mean(maxtab, 0)[1]' on the results
    """
    
    maxtab = []
    mintab = []
    maxthresh = []
    minthresh = []

    if x_axis is None:
        x = arange(len(y_axis))
    else:
        x = asarray(x_axis)

    y = asarray(y_axis)

    if len(y) != len(x):
        sys.exit('Input vectors y and x must have same length')

    if not isscalar(peak_height):
        sys.exit('Input argument peak_height must be a scalar')

    # if peak_height <= 0:
    #     sys.exit('Input argument peak_height must be positive')

    # maxima and minima candidates are temporarily stored in mx and mn respectively:
    mn, mx = np.Inf, -np.Inf
    mnpos, mxpos = NaN, NaN
    
    # Obtaining the maximum and minimum peaks of the signal:
    key_list = list(x)
    value_list = list(y)
    signal_dict = dict(zip(key_list, value_list))
    signal_full_dict = defaultdict(list)
    for key, value in chain(signal_dict.items()):
        signal_full_dict[key].append(value)
    max_peak = max(signal_full_dict.items(), key = lambda x: x[1])[1]
    min_peak = min(signal_full_dict.items(), key = lambda x: x[1])[1]
    mxpkpos = max(signal_full_dict.items(), key = lambda x: x[1])[0]
    mnpkpos = min(signal_full_dict.items(), key = lambda x: x[1])[0]
    maxtab.append((mxpkpos, max_peak))
    mintab.append((mnpkpos, min_peak))
    
    y_ax = list(y_axis)
    
    for x_v, y_v in y_ax:
        if y_v > peak_height:
            maxthresh.append((x_v, y_v))
        elif y_v < -peak_height:
            minthresh.append((x_v, y_v))
            
    for x_val, y_val in maxthresh:
        try:
            if (y[x_val - 1][1] > y_val) & (y[x_val + 1][1] < y_val):
                maxtab.append((x_val, y_val))
        except Exception:
            pass

    for x_val, y_val in minthresh:
        try:
            if (y[x_val - 1][1] < y_val) & (y[x_val + 1][1] < y_val):
                mintab.append((x_val, y_val))
        except Exception:
            pass

    return [maxtab, mintab]
    # return array(maxtab), array(mintab)
```

I was wondering what could be the reason for this error and how do I fix it?

Comment: Well, y_ax isn't a list of tuples, but a list of floats, so you cannot unpack it in two variables.

Comment: @unil I managed to change to create empty list and combine both x and y into the list '    y_ax.append((x, y))'. Now I get the following error: ' if y_v > peak_height:

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem, Here is the updated function:

```
def custom_peakdetection(y_axis, peak_height, x_axis=None):
    """
    keyword arguments:
    y_axis -- A list containing the signal over which to find peaks
    x_axis -- A x-axis whose values correspond to the 'y_axis' list and is used in the return to specify the position of the peaks. If omitted the index of the y_axis is used. (default: None)
    data_ahead -- (optional) distance to look ahead and previous from a peak candidate to determine if it is the actual peak
    peak_height -- (optional) This specifies a minimum height of the peak
    
    return -- two lists [maxtab, mintab] containing the positive and negative peaks respectively. Each cell of the lists contains a tuple of:
    (position, peak_value) to get the average peak value do 'np.mean(maxtab, 0)[1]' on the results
    """
    
    maxtab = []
    mintab = []
    maxthresh = []
    minthresh = []

    if x_axis is None:
        x = arange(len(y_axis))
    else:
        x = asarray(x_axis)

    y = asarray(y_axis)

    if len(y) != len(x):
        sys.exit('Input vectors y and x must have same length')

    if not isscalar(peak_height):
        sys.exit('Input argument peak_height must be a scalar')

    # if peak_height <= 0:
    #     sys.exit('Input argument peak_height must be positive')

    # maxima and minima candidates are temporarily stored in mx and mn respectively:
    mn, mx = np.Inf, -np.Inf
    mnpos, mxpos = NaN, NaN
    
    # Obtaining the maximum and minimum peaks of the signal:
    key_list = list(x)
    value_list = list(y)
    signal_dict = dict(zip(key_list, value_list))
    signal_full_dict = defaultdict(list)
    for key, value in chain(signal_dict.items()):
        signal_full_dict[key].append(value)
    max_peak = max(signal_full_dict.items(), key = lambda x: x[1])[1]
    min_peak = min(signal_full_dict.items(), key = lambda x: x[1])[1]
    mxpkpos = max(signal_full_dict.items(), key = lambda x: x[1])[0]
    mnpkpos = min(signal_full_dict.items(), key = lambda x: x[1])[0]
    maxtab.append((mxpkpos, max_peak))
    mintab.append((mnpkpos, min_peak))
    
    for i in arange(1, len(y)):
        this = y[i]
        if (this > peak_height):
            mx = this
            mxpos = x[i]
            maxthresh.append((mxpos, mx))
        if (this < peak_height):
            mn = this
            mnpos = x[i]
            minthresh.append((mnpos, mn))
    
    # print(maxthresh)
    # print(minthresh)

    for x_val, y_val in maxthresh:
        try:
            if (y[x_val - 1][1] > y_val) & (y[x_val + 1][1] < y_val):
                maxtab.append((x_val, y_val))
        except Exception:
            pass

    for x_val, y_val in minthresh:
        try:
            if (y[x_val - 1][1] < y_val) & (y[x_val + 1][1] < y_val):
                mintab.append((x_val, y_val))
        except Exception:
            pass

    print(maxtab)
    print(mintab)

    return [maxtab, mintab]
    # return array(maxtab), array(mintab)
```